# How to get the correct format of Date in jquery

Tags: jquery

**I have pass the date as the parameter like this:

```
onClick="GetCreateTaskPopup(\'' + full.ID + '\',\'' + full.Category + '\',\'' + full.ClientName + '\',\'' + full.DateCreated + '\')" />';
```

.

```
function GetCreateTaskPopup(ID, Category, ClientName, DateCreated) {
    var getDate = DateCreated; // in the getDate variale i a getting this value /Date(1629138600000)/
}
```

Here full.DateCreated is my passing value, when I am receiving this date value using the JQuery method I am not getting the correct format, I am getting the format like this `/Date(1629138600000)/` but my actual date is `10/28/2021`

Can you please help me on this...**

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is a Unix timestamp (in msecs). We cannot know what your `GetCreateTaskPopup()` does, but you can use built-in formatting functions or write your own format. Or maybe the popup has an option to take a timestamp instead of a date? It will likely convert the date string into a timestamp internally anyway.

You probably want something like [toIsoString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString), assuming the component takes any standard datetime format:

```js
full.DateCreated.toISOString()
```

I would also suggest to take a look at [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) if that is not enough.

See [JavaScript: Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) documentation to see formatting options.